# Multidimensional dynamic time warping

Tags: time-series, dynamic-time-warping

I am trying to understand how to extend the idea of one dimensional dynamic time warping to the multidimensional case.

Lets assume I have a dataset with two dimensions where `TrainA` holds dimension 1 and `TrainB` holds dimension 2. It seems that the simplest case would be

```
distA = dtw(TrainA) 
distB = dtw(TrainB) 
dist = distA + distB  // or maybe distA*distB
```

Is this the right approach? I know there are packages that do this for you but I want to understand what is actually being done.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to do it. The way you describe is DTWI, but other way, DTWD can be better, because it pools the information before warping.

There is an explanation of the differences, and an empirical study here.
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Multi-Dimensional_DTW_Journal.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link to the great paper! Do you know if any code exists that will extend the UCR suite (http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/UCRsuite.html) to allow for DTWD? In case this is Professor Eamonn, I love your work!

Comment: @mike1886 this is somewhat a separate question, but it should be noted that the code for the linked paper is available https://sites.google.com/site/dtwadaptive/home

Comment: Why is pooling information before warping better?